# External Swf issues

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external

I am working with external swfs. A main class loads in many external swfs immediately. They are shown later on after user input.

Just one of the external swfs is an issue. I wrote this, it is a different interaction then the rest and the audio played is separate from the main class unlike the other swfs.

So my question is, in the external swf code, is there an event listener I can use to know when this external swf is being displayed in The main class? I don't want to change the main class code since it is setup for a template that this one swf can't and won't match. Any suggestions would be great Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you are doing with this child swf, it is a pity that you are not in a position to change your main class, I mean this is in charge of the children right.

I think you could possibly do the following in your child swf:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler, false, 0, true);

function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
{
   var child:Movieclip = MovieClip(event.currentTarget);
   // do something with child
}
```